# About $\|1\|\neq1$ for operator algebras.

Tags: operator-theory

Let a normed algebra $A\ni1$ non-null. Suppose that $\|1\|\neq1$. Show that

(i) $\|1\|\geq1$;

(ii) $A$ have another $\|\cdot\|_n$ norm equivalent to $\|\cdot\|$ such that $\|1\|_n=1$ and $A$ still is a normed algebra;

(iii) Give a example of normed algebra with $\|1\|_m=2023$.

About item (i) it's ok, cause $\|1\|=\|1\cdot1\|\leq\|1\|\|1\|=\|1\|^2$. To (ii) I tried what follows

Let $u\mapsto\|u\|_\star=\|L_u\|$, where $L_u$ is defined by $a\in A\mapsto L_u(a)=ua$. We have $\|\cdot\|_\star$ is norm. Note that
\begin{align*}
    \|1\|_\star
    =\|L_1\|
    =\sup_{a\in B_A}\|a\|
    =1.
\end{align*}
$\|\cdot\|_\star$ is submultiplicative (this point I can't prove it). In fact,
\begin{align}
    \|ab\|_\star
    =\|L_{ab}\|
    =\sup_{v\in B_A}\|abv\|
    &\leqslant\sup_{u\in B_A}\|au\|\sup_{v\in B_A}\|bv\|\\
    &=\|L_a\|\|L_b\|=\|a\|_\star\|b\|_\star,
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is almost enough, good job! You have, for any $x\in A$,
We have
$$
\|L_ax\|=\Big\|a\,\frac{x}{\|x\|}\Big\|\,\|x\|\leq\|L_a\|\,\|x\|. 
$$
Then
$$
\|ab\|_\star=\|L_{ab}\|=\|L_aL_b\|=\sup_{v\in B_A}\|L_aL_bv\|\leq\|L_a\|\,\sup_{v\in B_A}\|L_bv\|=\|L_a\|\,\|L_b\|
=\|a\|_\star\|b\|_\star. 
$$
You also need to show that $\|\cdot\|_\star$ is a norm, but that's not too hard.

And now  you can easily do (iii): you define $\|a\|_m=2023\,\|a\|_\star$.

Comment: Why $\|a\|\|bv\|\leq\|a\|_\star\|b\|_\star$? How you get it? Is this what wanna prove it, or at least anything else. Note that $\|1\|>\|1\|_\star$.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I'm too used to think that $\|1\|=1$.

Comment: I put another argument, take a look.

Comment: The trick is that $L_{ab}=L_aL_b$, thaks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. This is a nice proof.